# Javascript push array item to named index

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexing, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON array:

> [{   id: 1,   client: "Microsoft" },{   id: 2,   client: "Microsoft"
>   },{   id: 3,   client: "Apple" }]

and I'd like to group it by "client", but I'm having difficulty with this in javascript. In PHP i'd typically do something like this:

```
$group = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {

    $group[ $item['client'] ] = $item;

}

return $group;
```

But this method totally wont't work in javascript on a multidimensional array

```
var group = [];

for ( i=0 ... ) {

  var client = array[i].client;

  group[ client ].push( array[i] );

}
```

How would I go about grouping the above array into something like this:

> [{ "Microsoft": [{...}], "Apple":[{...}] }]

or even

> [{ client: "Microsoft", "items": [{...}] }, { client: "Apple", items: [{...}]  }]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an object for that, not an array:

```
var array = [{ id: 1, client: "Microsoft" },{ id: 2, client: "Microsoft" },{ id: 3, client: "Apple" }];
var group = {};
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  var client = array[i].client;
  group[client] = group[client] || []; // create array for client if needed
  group[client].push(array[i]);
}
console.log(group);
```

It's important to keep in mind that the resulting object will contain *references* to the objects from the original array. For example:

```
array[0].id = 100;
group.Microsoft[0].id; // 100
```